How to get LazyColumn click position
I have a LazyColumn, click one item to navigate to a new screen. I want the Animation transition to be similar to the Gmail app to open a mail to the detail page. I don't need to use the SharedElementTransition. But I still need to know the click item position. Please help.
LazyColumn(
modifier = Modifier
.fillMaxSize()
.pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectTapGestures { offset ->
        clickPosition.value = offset
        Log.d(TAG, offset.x+"--"+offset.y)
    }
},
) {
    items(list) { item ->
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable {
            }) {
        }
    }
}

The code is above, I can get the log to print the offset if I click on the screen except on the LazyColumn, but I want to get the offset of the item I clicked which is in the LazyColumn.

Please share with us the code you have so far. Make sure to remove everything that isn't stricly necessary to demonstrate what you're trying to achieve.

You already have an onClick inside the column that should print the item data, if you need the index you could use :
itemsIndexed(){ index, item->
   ..... 
}

instead of items.
In the clickable lamda just save the position of the item or save the item itself if you need it inside a variable of your choice
